# Unable to switch from Native app to webview android browser

Tags: android, android-webview, appium

In my app. When I am clicking on "create account using google" option it's redirecting to webview, So now I tried with this code

```
Set<String> text = ((AndroidDriver) driver).getContextHandles();

System.out.println(text);

for (String contexts : text) {
    String setContext = text.toArray()[1].toString();
    System.out.println(setContext);
    ((AndroidDriver) driver).context(setContext);
}
```

here it the output I am getting

> [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.android.browser]

for text and
`WEBVIEW_com.android.browser.` -  for `setContext`.
But after switching I am not able to click on an element. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: getting exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: chrome not reachable

Comment: Still I am not getting any answer on this